# I'd like to know the answer (what is "to know the answer")

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitives, to-infinitive, parsing

In the sentence:

> I would like to know the answer.

What is "to know the answer" here?
Is it a participle functioning as an object,
a verbal modifying like,
an infinitive functioning as an object
the predicate of the sentence?

Comment: Can we have the entire question from the test or exercise, please? It's not clear what you mean by _"...an infinitive functioning as an object the predicate of the sentence."_

Answer (score 1):

Because the entirety of "to know the answer" acts as a single unit (the object of the verb "would like"). It is an [infinitive phrase or clause](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/infinitive-phrase) which is :

> a group of words that begins with an infinitive and functions as a noun, adjective, or adverb.

Answer (score 1):

In some grammars, *to know the answer* is analyzed as an infinitival clause functioning as the direct object of the verb 'like'.

In CGEL (Huddleston and Pullum et al, 2002), however, it's analyzed as an infinitival clause that functions as a catenative complement of the catenative verb 'like'. It's called 'catenative' because of its ability to form chains in a catenative construction.

Answer (score 0):

This can get complicated.

But the short answer is: it's called the to-infinitive. [to infinitive](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive)

There is an entire list via the blue link. Verbs of thinking and feeling and verbs of saying take a to infinitive.

There are more complicated linguistic analyses of this, but for ELL purposes, one just has to learn them by heart (at first).

Comment: And an  "an infinitive functioning as an object" which is what the OP wanted to know.